# Telegram bot API edit InlineKeyboard with python-telegram-bot not working

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to create a menu where the user can navigate on it. This is my code:

```
MENU, HELP = range(2)

def start(bot, update):
    keyboard = [
                 [InlineKeyboardButton('Help', callback_data='help')]
               ]

    # Create initial message:
    message = 'Welcome.'

    update.message.reply_text(message, reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))

def help(bot, update):

    keyboard = [
                 [InlineKeyboardButton('Leave', callback_data='cancel')]
               ]


    update.callback_query.edit_message_reply_markup('Help ... help..', reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))

def cancel(bot, update):

    update.message.reply_text('Bye.', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())

    return ConversationHandler.END     


# Create the EventHandler and pass it your bot's token.
updater = Updater(token=config.TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN)

# Get the dispatcher to register handlers:
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(help, pattern='help'))
dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(cancel, pattern='cancel'))

updater.start_polling()

updater.idle()
```

As expected, at the /start the user gets the menu 'Help'. When the user clicks on it, the function help() is triggered as expected as well.

Based on my understanding of the python-telegram-bot documentation is was supposed to have the **update.callback_query.inline_message_id** populated, but its value is **None**.

I need the **update.callback_query.inline_message_id** to update my InlineKeyboard menu, right ? Why is the inline_message_id empty (None) ?

```
Python 3.6.7
python-telegram-bot==11.1.0
```

Best Regards.
Kleyson Rios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there are 2 problems in your code.

**First**. In your `help` function, you're trying to change both the **text** of the message and the **markup** of it. But the `edit_message_reply_markup` method *only changes the markup*. So instead of

```
update.callback_query.edit_message_reply_markup(
    'Help ... help..',
    reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
)
```

Do this:

```
bot.edit_message_text(
    text='Help ... help..',
    chat_id=update.callback_query.message.chat_id,
    message_id=update.callback_query.message.message_id,
    reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
)
bot.answer_callback_query(update.callback_query.id, text='')
```

Notice the changes:

- I replaced `update.callback_query` with `bot`.
- **IMPORTANT**: I replaced `edit_message_reply_markup` with `edit_message_text`; Because the first one *only changes the markup*, but the second one can do both.
- I added `chat_id` and `message_id` arguments; Because [that's what it says in the documents](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.edit_text).
- *IMPORTANT*: I added a new method (`bot.answer_callback_query`); Because every time you handle a *callback query* you need to *answer* it (using this method). However, you can leave the `text` argument *empty*, so that it doesn't show anything.

**Second**. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe when the user presses the `cancel` button, you want the text of the message to be *changed* to "Bye." and *remove the keyboard*. If this is the case, what you're doing wrong is that you're sending a *new* message (`reply_text`) while trying to remove the keyboard (`reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()`). You can simply do it like this:

```
bot.edit_message_text(
    text='Bye',
    chat_id=update.callback_query.message.chat_id,
    message_id=update.callback_query.message.message_id,
)
bot.answer_callback_query(update.callback_query.id, text='')
```

Here, the idea is that when you edit the *text* of the message and don't use a markup keyboard, the *previous* keyboard gets automatically *removed*, so you don't need to use `ReplyKeyboardRemove()`.

Here's a GIF (with a hard G) that it works!

[image]

Comment: Thanks Amir. It worked like a charm :). This is my first time trying to write a telegram bot and all those details that you gave are what I miss on the telegram bot API.

Comment: @KleysonRios You got it, glad to help ^_^